# calculus volume problem

Tags: calculus, integration

I need to set up an integral for the volume of a solid obtained by rotating about the y-axis the region bounded by the curves $$y=x^2 \quad \text{and} \quad x^2+y^2=2$$

Now, I know that $x^2+y^2=2$ is the equation of a circle with radius $\sqrt{2}$. I think this problem would be better solved using the washer method and I want to integrate with respect to $y$, but then I ave no idea what the outer and inner radii would be. Some help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't washers---it's disks---since the region to be rotated is totally adjacent to the axis of rotation. Here's a picture:

[image]

Take a representative slice at height $y$, of thickness $\Delta y$. Note that the curves intersect at $(\pm 1,1)$ and the circle has radius $\sqrt{2}$.

- For $0<y<1$, the radius of the disk follows the parabola $y=x^2\implies x=\sqrt{y}$, so $r=\sqrt{y}\implies V_\text{slice}=\pi(\sqrt{y})^2\Delta y \implies V_\text{lower}=\int_0^1 \pi\,y\,dy$.
- For $1<y<\sqrt 2$, the radius of the disk follows the upper half of the circle $x^2+y^2=2\implies x=\sqrt{2-y^2}$, so $r=\sqrt{2-y^2}\implies V_\text{slice}=\pi(\sqrt{2-y^2})^2\Delta y \implies V_\text{upper}=\int_1^\sqrt{2} \pi\,(2-y^2)\,dy$.

The total volume is $V=V_\text{lower}+V_\text{upper}$.

Comment: I was being silly, of course I meant disks! Thank you very much.